# Pardot - using merge fields in an URL link

Tags: pardot

I'm trying to embed the following link in a Pardot email template:
`https://<mydomain>.secure.force.com/customRest/ContactUpToDate?id=%%crm_contact_fid%%&ob=1`

But it gives me the following error:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fish around for the proper SFID merge field.  The merge field for the SFID on a contact is `crm_id` and the final link looks like this:

`https://<mydomain>.secure.force.com/customRest/ContactUpToDate?id=%%crm_id%%&ob=1`